# Different std::map size when inserting with operator[] (vc++ vs g++)

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, language-lawyer, stdmap

This code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::size_t> m;
    m[0] = m.size();
    std::cout << m[0] << std::endl;
}
```

will print `0` with [vc++](https://rextester.com/PPQMCY57133) and `1` with [g++](https://rextester.com/LDQG1362).

- Is this code valid?
- If yes, which compiler is correct?
- Intuitively I would expect `1`. How does vc++ end up with `0`?

Comment: this is undefined behavior. Order of evaluating `m[0]` and `m.size()` is not defined.

Comment: @MarekR thank you, could you point to where to look for explanation why?

Comment: @MarekR Didn't `c++17` change things such that the right hand side is always evaluated first in this case?

Comment: @G.M. [it looks like it](https://rextester.com/SIX95780)

Comment: @MarekR Unspecified != Undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since C++17 the [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order#Rules) is guaranteed, `m.size()` is sequenced before `m[0]`; the result is guaranteed to be `0`.

> 20. In every simple assignment expression E1=E2 and every compound assignment expression E1@=E2, every value computation and side-effect of E2 is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of E1

Before C++17 the behavior is [unspecified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub#Explanation).

BTW you can observe different behaviors with [Gcc C++17 mode](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MM4DXHlsmF9obrh0) and [Gcc C++14 mode](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uzcaMi0eKDyN5UYc).

Comment: Before C++17, the behavior is unspecified, but not undefined. `m[0]` and `m.size()` are both function calls. The execution of their bodies cannot overlap. This is the case even if their call sites are unsequenced.

Answer (score 3):

[Assignment operators - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment)

> When the left operand has reference type, the assignment operator modifies the referred-to object.
>
> If the left and the right operands identify overlapping objects, the behavior is undefined (unless the overlap is exact and the type is the same)